# Theorems invoked to evaluate the finiteness of a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stopping-times

I would like to know **what are the theorems and/or results invoked** in this kinds of equalities:

$$
P_x[\tau_r < \infty] = \lim_{R\to\infty}P_x[\tau_{r,R}=\tau_r]
$$

where, to give an example rearranging part of the proof of Theorem 25.40 of Probability Theory by A. Klenke (3rd version),

- $\tau_s=\inf\{t>0: W_t=s\}$ and $\tau_{r,R}=\inf\{t>0: W_t\notin G_{r,R}\}$ are stopping times related to a Brownian motion $W$ started in $x\in(r,R)$ and an interval $G_{r,R}:=(r,R)$ with $-\infty<r<0<R<\infty$

My two ideas of what could be involved:

1. Monotone Convergence Theorem: I can't figure out what is the sequence of function involved in the second equality. In particular, I do not know how to treat the indicator function to "bring out the limit from the set". For the first equality I do not know what could be a useful result to show that it holds.

$$
E_x[\mathcal{I}_{\{\tau_r<\infty\}}]=E_x[\mathcal{I}_{\{\lim_{R\to\infty}\tau_{r,R}=\tau_r\}}]=\lim_{R\to\infty}E_x[\mathcal{I}_{\{\tau_{r,R}=\tau_r\}}]
$$

2. Or, define the events $A_R:=\{\tau_{r,R}=\tau_r\}$; see that this is an increasing sequence (how can I prove it?) of events that converge to $A=\{\tau_r<\infty\}$. Then use the lower semi continuity property of the probability measure $P_x[\cdot]$

Please, let me know if more context is needed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is $G_{r,R}$?

Comment: I just edited my OP. I forgot to write it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\{\tau_{r,R}=\tau_r \}=\{\tau_r<\tau_R\}$. As $R\to \infty$ the stopping time $\tau_R$ increases to $\infty$, so the event $\{\tau_r<\tau_R\}$ increases to $\{\tau_r< \infty\}$. This sets up your idea 2.

Comment: Why $\tau_R$ increases to $\infty$? Because $W$ will, almost surely, never be $\infty$? Thank you.

Comment: Yes: $W$ being continuous, $\max_{0\le s\le t}W_s$ is finite for each $t>0$.